# Bluetooth randomly restarts while connected to speakers

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, bluez

I spent the whole day figuring out why my Linux Mint won't work anymore with my bluetooth speakers (and it used to a couple of months ago). The good thing about this issue is that it made me finally update my system (i.e. I am running Linux Mint 19.3).

```
felix@felix ~ $ bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.50
```

Connecting to my speakers works and if I am lucky, the connection stays up for a couple of seconds and I can hear the sound. However, at some point the connection breaks. From the logs it looks to me that the whole bluetooth service is being restarted for some reason, because this is what shows there in that second:

```
Jun  1 22:42:43 felix kernel: [ 1358.725890] usb 3-7: USB disconnect, device number 11
Jun  1 22:42:43 felix acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 18
Jun  1 22:42:43 felix bluetoothd[7507]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  1 22:42:43 felix bluetoothd[7507]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix NetworkManager[2472]: <info>  [1591044163.9861] bluez5: NAP: removed interface AD:E9:25:D1:52:37
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd-rfkill[7547]: Failed to open device rfkill9: No such device
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix kernel: [ 1359.001760] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix kernel: [ 1359.130692] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix kernel: [ 1359.130695] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix kernel: [ 1359.144660] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100180012d0d2a
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix kernel: [ 1359.144662] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 2a
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix laptop-mode: enabled, not active
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix NetworkManager[2472]: <info>  [1591044164.4263] bluez5: NAP: added interface AD:E9:25:D1:52:37
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix systemd[1]: Started Session c27 of user felix.
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix bluetoothd[7507]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  1 22:42:44 felix bluetoothd[7507]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.49 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

What's also strange about it is that I am not connecting or disconnecting any USB device (like the logs suggest).

Bluetooth is not blocked by rfkill either:

```
felix@felix ~ $ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```

Any ideas?